# Output a image in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel/Vue 2.0 project working and need help to display images

I upload the image in the laravel controller like so:

```php
//Save image to disk
        if($request->hasFile('image')) {

            $image = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Storage::disk('public')->put($image->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($image));
            $article->image_path = $image->getFilename().'.'.$extension;

        } else {
            $article->image_path = 'holding.jpg';
        }
```

Then I created a storage link by using:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then I out put like so:

```
<img v-bind:src="'/storage/' + article.image_path" class="card-img-top" :alt="article.title">
```

From that I get a image not found on the front end.

Comment: Have you checked that `article.image_path` is set? If it is, can you confirm that the image path matches the path in the URL?

Comment: If the image is not found ***a)*** there's something wrong with your request (either the URL, or maybe some headers, maybe credentials (if server requires any), etc...) or ***b)*** there's something wrong with your server (as in: request is what it should be but it's misconfigured and it doesn't respond as expected. If it's a), fix the request. If it's b) fix the server. However, I'd argue it has little to do with Vue. You could be using angular, react, vanilla or svelte, the approach for fixing this would be the same, somewhat unrelated to the framework itself.

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser console to pinpoint the request (it's typically red) and take it from there. If network tab is empty when you open it, refresh the page and you'll probably see the faulty one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check `article` value with Vue extension for Firefox or Chrome, and also inspect img tag, in order to understand what is happening.

Comment: So the image is getting a 200 in the network tab but the only thing i see that could be an issue is ```Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8``` in the response

Comment: So, it is not an image, or the backend is providing the wrong Content-Type.

Comment: Try to open the request in another tab, right clicking in the request in network tab

Comment: So opening the image in a new tab from the request just gives me a new page, so I think its not being seen as an image

Comment: New blank page? Inspect it, view source... Also look in Laravel logs, if any.

Answer (score 0):

So it seemed to be an issue with storage and laravel

I updated the controller to store the image in the public folder direct

```php
$image->move(public_path('/img/blog_images'), $image->getFilename().'.'.$extension,);
```

Then hit that in the view

```html
<img :src="'/img/blog_images/' + article.image_path"
     class="card-img-top"
     :alt="article.title"
/>
```

All works great!